# how are form labels translated in symfony2?

Tags: forms, symfony, translation, label

I'm using the internal Translation extension in Symfony2 to create a message.en.yml file with the translations. While most of the elements are recorded with a distinct name, the field names( or possibly the entity properties, I'm not sure) are cataloged with only their names. This makes it very difficult to handle them.

For example, this a sample of my message.en.yml:

- address.contactdocumentnumber.list: __address.contactdocumentnumber.list
- address.contactdocumentnumber.add.new: __address.contactdocumentnumber.add.new
- contactDocumentnumber: __contactDocumentnumber
- issuingAuthority: __issuingAuthority
- documentType: __documentType

As you can see the field names: contactDocumentnumber, issuingAuthority, documentType are stored with only their names where what I want is something like *address.contactdocumentnumber.form.label.issuingAuthority*

How can I change this?
And more importantly, where is the template for translations located in a Symfony2 project?

I have noticed that when I change the label in the Form Builder, it does show in my form. But when I run the command "php app/console translate:update --force en MyByndle" the field name is still the same e.g. __fieldname. Is it possible it takes the name from somewhere else, like the entity for example?

Answer (score 0):

By default Symfony guesses the label based on the name of the field. So a field named `some_field` will get the label `Some field`. If you want to override that, you can pass a `label` option with your translatable string when building the field. For example:

```
$builder->add('some_field', 'text', [
    'label' => 'section.some_field_label'
]);
```

Comment: I have tried that already, but still, when I run "php app/console translation:update --force en MyBundle" I don't see any changes.

Comment: Ah sorry, seems I misunderstood your question. Have you tried the [JMSTranslationBundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSTranslationBundle) yet? It seems to be able to extract the labels from form fields built with the FormBuilder.

Comment: Thanks. I will check the bundle you propose.